# Inserting numbers from excel to Visual Studio C# code editor as two-dimensional double array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do I in a relative quick and automatic way reformat tabular number data to a two-dimensional double array in Visual Studio 2019?

It's tedious to do it manually by inserting every comma and brace. What shortcuts can I use? Any snippets available for this?

**Background**

I'm creating unit tests and have some test data in excel. I don't have that much data in the Excel that I would want to use a data test method which imports the data directly from Excel.

I'm asking this primarily to learn how to use VS more effectively.

I have copied a range of numbers from excel (rows and columns) to the C# editor in Visual Studio 2019 and want to reformat it quickly to double 2d arrays.

**Example**

So this is an example of what I have copied in VS editor:

```
30.588011687919100  3.552739604442900   0.355273960444290   0.232793306291847   0.386960805120000   0.822759847113580   0.205380377705994   0.000026801813820
3.816841493065990   0.443318907899208   0.044331890789921   0.029048476894419   0.523189168320000   1.021312950913700   0.616518035583194   0.000040450056918
0.841586263233737   0.097748649976046   0.009774864997605   0.006404981492320   0.602827288320000   1.136567304900470   1.157206512470570   0.000056344305018
0.211757937773250   0.024595283268422   0.002459528326842   0.001611606238769   0.662241929920000   1.237357310704140   1.860999653438160   0.000072386758744
0.306225693784172   0.035567534147201   0.003556753414720   0.002330563112596   0.637716718080000   1.203901579266380   1.737471112229580   0.000072370443918
0.059045217195918   0.006857990108187   0.000685799010819   0.000449369886215   0.744742030080000   1.337082693586410   2.762270022202240   0.000090028703785
81.800693360348700  9.500995551370890   0.950099555137089   0.622552850397991   0.435898528000000   0.595278314777699   0.088285602360508   0.000024049812257
5.755803209663900   0.668525637657870   0.066852563765787   0.043805150632661   0.707983800000000   1.026123663891300   0.406895290225844   0.000026676261926
1.779547768668850   0.206691101737902   0.020669110173790   0.013543436984376   0.526166800000000   1.123244442667640   0.553330848755109   0.000027012836660
6.236068174143770   0.724307503355532   0.072430750335553   0.047460258068806   0.503781928000000   0.981092091111613   0.491109901720685   0.000036274835045
```

And this is the double 2D array I created manually

```
double[,] expected = {
            { 30.588011687919100,  3.552739604442900,   0.355273960444290,   0.232793306291847,   0.386960805120000,   0.822759847113580,   0.205380377705994,   0.000026801813820 },
            {  3.816841493065990,  0.443318907899208,   0.044331890789921,   0.029048476894419,   0.523189168320000,   1.021312950913700,   0.616518035583194,   0.000040450056918 },
            {  0.841586263233737,   0.097748649976046,   0.009774864997605,   0.006404981492320,   0.602827288320000,   1.136567304900470,   1.157206512470570,   0.000056344305018 },
            {  0.211757937773250,   0.024595283268422,   0.002459528326842,   0.001611606238769,   0.662241929920000,   1.237357310704140,   1.860999653438160,   0.000072386758744 },
            {  0.306225693784172,   0.035567534147201,   0.003556753414720,  0.002330563112596,   0.637716718080000,   1.203901579266380,   1.737471112229580,   0.000072370443918 },
            {  0.059045217195918,   0.006857990108187,   0.000685799010819,   0.000449369886215,   0.744742030080000,   1.337082693586410,   2.762270022202240,   0.000090028703785 },
            { 81.800693360348700,  9.500995551370890,   0.950099555137089,   0.622552850397991,   0.435898528000000,   0.595278314777699,   0.088285602360508,   0.000024049812257 },
            {  5.755803209663900,   0.668525637657870,   0.066852563765787,   0.043805150632661,   0.707983800000000,   1.026123663891300,   0.406895290225844,   0.000026676261926 },
            {  1.779547768668850,   0.206691101737902,   0.020669110173790,   0.013543436984376,   0.526166800000000,   1.123244442667640,   0.553330848755109,   0.000027012836660 },
            {  6.236068174143770,   0.724307503355532,   0.072430750335553,   0.047460258068806,   0.503781928000000,   0.981092091111613,   0.491109901720685,   0.000036274835045 }
            };
```

Comment: You could write a small C# program that dumps the desired result to a file and then copy it to your unit test.

Comment: Did you try oledb connection?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog Thanks for your suggestion. But as I said, I would use a data test method which reads the data directly from the Excel sheet if it was a lot of data. I primarily ask this to learn how to use VS 2019 C# editor more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

- Select only the part with number.
- Press CTRL+H and open the replace box. Ensure the regex is activated
  (the button with ".*" on it), and the combo is set to "Selection".
- Then replace space(or tab?) char with a comma, "\r\n" with "}{".

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to automate this task. (If it matches your definition to use VS more effectively.)

A Visual Commander command can read data directly from the clipboard, execute a small C# script to reformat it and then insert into the VS editor.